# Aggregating array of object per category for big dataset

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting, recharts

I'm trying to prepare data for a graph, but my library expects each object to be on an aggregated level. At times it can be more than 1000 objects which needs to be processed into one aggregated level, so I'm trying to find a rather performant solution (performant in Javascript..). I want to aggregate and make one object on month level - but my data is on daily level.

What my array looks like now:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "1 Jan 2022",
    uv: 2000,
    pv: 400,
 
  },
 {
    name: "3 Jan 2022",
    uv: 1000,
    pv: 1500,
 
  },
 {
    name: "4 Jan 2022",
    uv: 1000,
    pv: 500,
 
  },
..........x 100 similar entries...  
]
```

Target array:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "Jan 2022",
    uv: 4000,
    pv: 2400,
 
  },
  {
    name: "Feb 2022",
    uv: 3000,
    pv: 1398,
  
  },
  {
    name: "Mar 2022",
    uv: 2000,
    pv: 9800,

  }
 ]
```

Any ideas on best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [{"name":"1 Jan 2022","uv":2000,"pv":400},{"name":"3 Jan 2022","uv":1000,"pv":1500},{"name":"4 Jan 2022","uv":1000,"pv":500}]

console.log(Object.values(data.reduce((a,{name,uv,pv},t)=>(
    t=name.substring(name.indexOf(' ')+1), 
    t=a[t]??={name:t,uv:0,pv:0},
    t.uv+=uv, t.pv+=pv,
  a), {})))
```

Without the advanced Javascript:

```js
const data = [{"name":"1 Jan 2022","uv":2000,"pv":400},{"name":"3 Jan 2022","uv":1000,"pv":1500},{"name":"4 Jan 2022","uv":1000,"pv":500}]

const byMonthAndYear = {}

data.forEach(i=>{
  let monthAndYear = i.name.substring(i.name.indexOf(' ')+1)
  if(!byMonthAndYear[monthAndYear]) {
    byMonthAndYear[monthAndYear] = {name:monthAndYear, uv:0, pv:0}
  }
  byMonthAndYear[monthAndYear].uv += i.uv
  byMonthAndYear[monthAndYear].pv += i.pv
})

console.log(byMonthAndYear)

const result = Object.values(byMonthAndYear)
    
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! It's very elegant, but the syntax is a bit advanced for me. I'm curious to learn, would you be interested to write a short explanation of what each line does and what each parameter represents? The "t" makes me a little bit confused, is this the index?

Comment: @OscarEkstrand I've used a lot of ES6 in the answer: [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [comma expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [Nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment).

Comment: I've used t as a temporary variable so that I don't have to call `name.substring` twice, and don't have to access `a[t]` twice. In order to avoid a `let t` before the console.log line, I've declared it in the function signature and then ignored anything `t` would be set to (in this case, reduce would have set it as the current index in the array) and immediately set it to what I need it to be set to

Comment: @OscarEkstrand I just added a non-advanced version. If you understand that, then you'll hopefully be able to see how I condensed it using advanced features

Comment: And keep in mind that the ancient `for` has better performance than `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using reduce:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "1 Jan 2022",
    uv: 2000,
    pv: 400,
 
  },
 {
    name: "3 Jan 2022",
    uv: 1000,
    pv: 1500,
 
  },
 {
    name: "4 Jan 2022",
    uv: 1000,
    pv: 500,
 
  },{
    name: "3 Feb 2022",
    uv: 1000,
    pv: 1500,
 
  },
 {
    name: "4 Feb 2022",
    uv: 60,
    pv: 500,
 
  },
 {
    name: "4 Feb 2023",
    uv: 60,
    pv: 500,
 
  }
 ]
  
 const result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const dt = item.name.split(" ");
  const month = dt[1] + ' ' + dt[2];
   if(!acc[month]){
     acc[month] = {
       name: month,
       pv: item.pv,
       uv: item.uv
     }
     return acc;
  }
     acc[month] = {
     name: month,
       pv: acc[month].pv += item.pv,
       uv: acc[month].uv += item.uv,
     }
  return acc;
 }, {}))
 
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm and is easy to read. I was deep on a path trying to use a Map combined with a for loop, but this is much more readable!

Comment: @OscarEkstrand awesome.  Reduce is a very powerful method.  Feel free to mark as answered :)